# Why is my wish list limited to one item?

Tags: magento

Im using magento 1.9 and im having an issue with the wishlist, for some reason it will only let me have one item in my wishlist and when I goto add another item to the wishlist it replaces the item that was already in my wishlist, there is nothing in the configuration to limit the wishlist item im just a bit confused at why it would be doing this, any ideas ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right!!, after hunting the web to try and find a solution I have found a solution, you have to edit the file `app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Model/Wishlist.php`

find:

```
public function getItemCollection()
```

and change

```
$this->_itemCollection =  Mage::getResourceModel('wishlist/item_collection')
                ->addWishlistFilter($this)
                ->addStoreFilter($this->getSharedStoreIds($currentWebsiteOnly))
                ->setVisibilityFilter();
```

to

```
$this->_itemCollection =  Mage::getResourceModel('wishlist/item_collection')
                ->addWishlistFilter($this)
                ->addStoreFilter($this->getSharedStoreIds($currentWebsiteOnly));
```

this worked for me and im using magento 1.9.0.1

the source for this fix is here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/291225/

Comment: Please note that you should never hack core. To add or modify functionality, either add the modified files in `app/code/local`, or create a module and rewrite the class.

Comment: Also note that you don't necessarily have to remove it. It'd be better if you 1) Comment it out, or 2) Set the value of the argument to `false` [(as it defaults to `true`)](http://doc-magento.com/app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Model/Resource/Item/Collection.php.source.html#l310)

Comment: I commented it out just incase, I need to revert back to how it was.

Answer (score 6):

This is an out of the box feature, you do not need to edit any core code to fix this.  Correction: *You don’t have to edit any code*

I had the same issue and found it was from an improper import of products and that website availability was incorrectly set.

It seems that Magento added a website filter on the wishlist collection to prevent items not available in a website from appearing in a customer's wishlist. 
It also seems that items may not have a website value => which prevents wish list items from appearing (or just 1 item, the last one added).

How to fix it : Simply select your store products on catalog page, select ‘Update Attributes’ action and click on submit. 
Select Websites panel and check your website in ‘Add Product To Websites’ block. 
Reindex your data if necessary.

You can now add your products to your wishlist and see all of them in your wishlist. This is the proper solution and does not remove functionality from your Magento webstore.

Comment: Nice, it happened to me with just one store. I think the problem is I used "duplicate product" in order to fulfill my catalog with test products. So, maybe it's a "bug" when you duplicate a product, because, with only one store, there is no chance to edit website. Thank you :)

Comment: No problem, glad me documenting my headache helped you out. Out of curiosity, how was the original product created?

Answer (score 2):

Simply reindex everything in: System > Index management

Comment: Thank you so much, you've just saved my life so bad ! Worked immediately after reindexing everyting and flushing the cache.

Comment: Actually, I had to change the index "Product Flat Data Reorganize EAV product structure to flat structure" to "Update on Save" to make the wishlist work automatically without having to reindex on each new product.