# Magento - Wishlist addNewItem remove all my items

Tags: php, magento

I got a problem with my whislist. Here is the thing.
I try to programmatically add into a whistlist, a new Item.
So I use the `$whishlist->addNewItem()` function. The product is added, but if I had other products in my whislist, they've been removed!

Here is what I use:

```
<?php
  $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($my_customer_id);
  $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($my_product_id);
  $wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer, true);  

  $request = new Varien_Object(array());
  $result = $wishlist->addNewItem($product, $request);  

  $wishlist->save();
?>
```

Did I do something wrong?

Thank you guys

**EDIT:**
I Finally found, it seems weird, but in my case, I have to remove this line `$wishlist->save();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `->save` on the wishlist. Sometimes it works

Comment: This is not a ideal way. Removing wishlist model save, won't solve problem. This is due to reindexing issue. Just reindex the catalog and it'll fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove this line `$wishlist->save();`
I don't know if it's THE solution, but it works for me.
Thank's to everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

This might help you, 
Lets say you have to add a product to wishlist on click so it would be like :

```
 <a onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl(Mage::registry('current_product'));?>')">add to wishlist</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem. But in my case product visibility in magento backend is set to "Not Visible Individually". changed product visibility and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the "save" function was not in cause.

My problem came from the products redindexation. I've found my solution here : [Why is my wish list limited to one item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27316747/why-is-my-wish-list-limited-to-one-item)

Reindexing every indexes made my wishlist worked again for products recently added through the rest API.

To do it automatically, I've change this index to "Update on Save" in the admin : **Product Flat Data** - Reorganize EAV product structure to flat structure.

My wishlist works perfectly fine now (even with the "save" function).